# Discord.js | How to make bot reply to the owner of a specific ID's messages without prefix

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

so basically I'm trying to make a command that when doing the command and providing an id, it will save it `!funi (ID)` and if it sees that the owner of the id sent a message it will say "shut up". I'm using MongoDB as a database. This is what the code looks like:

```
const Schema = require('../models/shut-schema')

module.exports = {
    name: 'funi',
    aliases: ['unfuni'],
    description: 'shut up noob',
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord){

        if(!args[0]) return message.reply('Please insert an ID so I can make them regret their life choices.');
        if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply("That's not an ID dumb dumb")
        
        const ID = args[0];

        Schema.findOne(async (err, data) => {
            if(data){
                data.ID = ID;
                data.save();
            } else {
                new Schema({
                    ID: ID
                }).save();
            }
            await message.reply("ID saved")
        })

        if (ID) message.reply("shut up")
    } 
}
```

and this is the shit-schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ID: String,
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Noobs', Schema)
```

but apparently, it's not working. it only responds when the owner of the id does the command and inserting an id. How do I make it so it will respond to all of the owner id's messages even without doing the prefix? Sorry if it's confusing.

PS. If it doesn't require a DB it's okay. I'm not sure if it does or not. Just wanted to include if it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer. I just had to put the command in the message event before it uses the prefix and now it works. I also added in guildID as a string so that each guild can have 1 noob.